# iptables: filter before DNAT

Tags: iptables, dnat

```
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -d 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner abc -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:121
```

First rule does not work because nat it processed before filter. Any way to bypass it?

Comment: Filtering on nat forwarding is done through the FORWARD table which is processed after nat.

Answer (score 4):

You are not required to filter anything before DNAT. You ask the wrong question.

You should have a look at [man iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) especially the module `conntrack` with its options `--ctstate DNAT`, `--ctorigdst`, and `--ctorigdstport`.

Comment: Do you think I am impressed by you ignoring what somebody with good `iptables` knowledge (in this case: me) told you? If you could assess what is "obviously" possible and what not with `iptables` then you would not ask such a beginner's question. Thus do as I told you: Have a look at the man page and realize how wrong you are.

Comment: This answer, while relatively short, was the solution to my problem of locking down docker containers to only certain source IPs and host destination ports. For a container `docker run -p 12380:80 nginx`, the command `iptables -I DOCKER -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT ! --ctorigsrc 172.17.8.1/32 --ctorigdstport 12380 -j REJECT` successfully restricted access so that only IP 172.17.8.1 (e.g. the Vagrant host) can access port 12380. In combination with a `PRE_DOCKER` chain dropping by default, this works better than any other solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner abc -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:121
```